# JS regex to only allow increments of 100

Tags: javascript, regex

What I want to do is **only allow increments of 100 in a number with either 3 or 4 digits**.

I get how to do it to a certain point, but what I thought would work isn't actually working as I'm getting no matches when testing. I think I now understand why, but I'm a little confused now as what to do to achieve my goal.

So what I want to do is only allow increments of 100 in an input, for instance `3700` would valid but `3723` would not.

What I came up with was this: `^[0-9]{1,2}[0]{2}$`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So what is actually wrong with your regex? What is the case when it behaves not as you expect it to? I can imagine some cases, but guessing is not how it is supposed to work - you need to make your problem clear and reproducable if you want to get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it simple, you need to match (in order):

1. One non-zero digit `[1-9]`.
2. Optionally followed by a single digit `\d?`.
3. Followed by two zeroes `00` (or `0{2}`, as you prefer).

Here you go:

```
^[1-9]\d?00$
```

Plus, this is probably not your case since you said you want to match either three or four digits, but **if you also want to match `0`** (zero):

```
^(0|[1-9]\d?00)$
```

---

**Test snippet** (zero excluded)

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('inp'),
    res = document.getElementById('res'),
    btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
    exp = /^[1-9]\d?00$/;

function test(e) {
    res.textContent = exp.test(inp.value) ? "Valid." : "Invalid.";
}

btn.addEventListener('click', test);
inp.addEventListener('change', test);
```

```html
<input id="inp"> <button id="btn">Submit</button>
<p id="res"></p>
```

Comment: @DCdaz that's because you need to specify the multiline (`m`) modifier if you want to test it on more lines, to make lines be treated as separated input strings. If you don't specify it, the `$` token in the regex will make it fail because the input is evaluated all at once. Take a look **[here](https://regex101.com/r/39B8mC/2)**.

Comment: Thanks mate, Taking this as answer

Answer (score 1):

This one should match your need : `^[1-9][0-9]?00$`

[Here is a sample](https://regex101.com/r/RGdoiU/1) on regex101

```
3100 // match
320
3320
100 // match
230
500 // match
5000 // match
1245
000
0000
50002
50000
12000
```

Comment: I guess that's because it will match `0000`

Comment: It matches a number with more than 4 digits, which is wrong.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Fixed ! I didn't saw the max 4 digits requirement ;)

Comment: It matches `123456789123456789000`

Comment: Not anymore ^^ LoL !

Comment: Still wrong, matches two non zeroes followed by three zeroes (e.g. `12000`).

Comment: I'm still alive guys ! fixed ! (again :))

Answer (score 1):

So your number must be `#000` or `#..#000`. So [`/^([1-9]00|[1-9]\d+00)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/rBVSM2/2)

---

**OR** Simply `number mod 100 == 0`:

```js
var input = prompt('Enter number');

if (input.match(/[^\d]/) || input % 100 != 0) {
  alert('Wrong input.');
} else {
  alert('Correct input');
}
```

Comment: `\d+` will match one or more digits after the first one. The OP said that the total number of digits can be either 3 or 4.